# Excel: rounding certain numbers to different rounding values

Tags: excel-formula, rounding

I'm trying find out how to round a cell that will have different results after calculation and I need to round the results to different values. The numbers and values are:

- < 5 to the nearest 0.5
- > 5 and < 20 to the nearest 1
- > 20 and < 50 to the nearest 5
- > 50 to the nearest 10.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See if this meets your needs:

```
=IF(A1<5,MROUND(A1,0.5),IF(A1<20,MROUND(A1,1),IF(A1<50,MROUND(A1,5),MROUND(A1,10))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses INDEX with MROUND:

```
=MROUND(A1,INDEX({0.5,1,5,10},MATCH(A1,{0,5,20,50})))
```